# How to do this in actionbar (2 vertical TextView)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Its posible to do this in actionbar sherlock? I know how set the icons but not the 2 textview in vertical layout posicion..This is a photoshop image

Comment: you can add custom  view in action bar.......

Comment: Im using api 10 and actionbarsherlock, its possible too?

Comment: yes .....Eevn I am using same for compatibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add custom view in action bar

```
 ActionBar ab =  this.getActionBar();
        if(null!=ab){
            ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            View cView =getLayoutInflater().inflate(<id>, null);
            ab.setCustomView(cView);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The action bar features both a title and a subtitle. If you set both, both will appear on top of each other.

One thing to note is that they will be left aligned which is counter to your photoshoped image (which seems to be removed).